# Python code for optimal alignment score and sequence giving wrong result

Tags: python, alignment, sequence, bioinformatics

This is my first time coding, so please do understand my code is very messy. I have done two different ways to get the optimal score and the optimal sequence, unfortunately both of my answers are wrong. In my code I have included a way to open a fasta file, but since this seemed to not work I also just included the sequences in the code myself.

My optimal score is computed but not printed for some reason- it is also wrong I have 208 when I should get 275. I also dont get a correct alignment score back. 
The two sequences are 
The scoring alignment needs to follow , 11 for internal gaps, 8 for terminal gaps on the 5' end, 7 for gaps on the 3' end, 4 for  mismatches, 0 for matches

My file is at [removed link]

```
     my_file = open("one.fasta","w")

 my_file.write (""">Testseq1
 TCTGGTGTCCTAGGCGTAGAGGAACCACACCAATCCATCCCGAACTCTGGTGGTTAAACTCTACTGCGGTGACGATACT""")

 sequenceone= open("one.fasta","r")

 line = sequenceone.readline()
 header = ""
 seqA = ""
 while line:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    if ">" in line:
    header = line 
else :
    seqA = seqA + line
line = sequenceone.readline()
my_file.close()

my_files = open("two.fasta","w")
my_files.write (""">Testseq2
TGGTGCGGTCATACCAGCGCTAATGCACCGGATCCCATCAGAACTCCGCAGTTAAGCGCGCTTGGGCCAGAACAGTACTGGGATGGGTGTCC""")
sequencetwo= open("two.fasta","r")

line = sequencetwo.readline()
header = ""
seqB = ""
while line:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
     if ">" in line:
        header = line 
    else :
        seqB = seqB + line
    line = sequencetwo.readline()
    my_files.close()

alphabet = ["A","C","G","T"]
score = [[8,8,8,8,8],\
         [0,4,4,4,11],\
         [4,0,4,4,11],\
         [4,4,0,4,11],\
         [4,4,4,0,11],\
         [7,7,7,7,7]]


def Global(a,b):
    D = []
    for i in range(len(a)+1):
        D.append([0]* (len(b)+1))

    for i in range(len(a)+1):
        D[i][0] = D[i-1][0] + score[alphabet.index(a[i-1])][-1]
    for i in range(len(b)+1):
        D[0][i] = D[0][i-1] + score[-1][alphabet.index(b[i-1])]

    for i in range (1, len(a)+1):
        for j in range (1, len(b)+1):
            distHor = D[i][j-1] + score[-1][alphabet.index(b[j-1])]
            distVer = D[i-1][j] + score[alphabet.index(a[i-1])][-1]
            if a[i-1] == b[j-1]:
                distDiag = D[i-1][j-1]
            else:
                distDiag = D[i-1][j-1] + score[alphabet.index(a[i-1])][alphabet.index(b[j-1])]

            D[i][j] = min(distHor, distVer, distDiag)

    return D[-1][-1]

seqA = "TCTGGTGTCCTAGGCGTAGAGGAACCACACCAATCCATCCCGAACTCTGGTGGTTAAACTCTACTGCGGTGACGATACT"
seqB = "TGGTGCGGTCATACCAGCGCTAATGCACCGGATCCCATCAGAACTCCGCAGTTAAGCGCGCTTGGGCCAGAACAGTACTGGGATGGGTGTCC"
row = len(seqA)+1
column = len(seqB)+1
match = 0
mismatch = 4
gap = 11
align1=""
align2=""
matrix=[[[[None] for i in range (2)] for i in range(column)] for i in range(row)]
for i in range(column):
    matrix[0][i][0]=gap*i
    if(i>0):
        matrix[0][i][1]="hor"
for i in range(row):
    matrix[i][0][0]=gap*i
    if(i>0):
        matrix[i][0][1]="ver"

for i in range(1,row):
    for j in range(1,column):
        hor=matrix[i][j-1][0]+gap
        ver=matrix[i-1][j][0]+gap
        if (seqA[i-1]==seqB[j-1]):
            diag=matrix[i-1][j-1][0]+match
        else:
            diag=matrix[i-1][j-1][0]+mismatch
        var = {hor:"hor",ver:"ver",diag:"diag"}
        hvd=[hor,ver,diag]
        matrix[i][j][0]=max(hvd)
        matrix[i][j][1]=var.get(max(var))

k=row
l=column
while(True):
    if(l==1 and k==1):
        break
    else:
        if(matrix[k-1][l-1][1]=="ver"):
            align1+=seqA[k-2]
            align2+="-"
            k-=1
        elif(matrix[k-1][l-1][1]=="hor"):
            align1+="-"
            align2+=seqB[l-2]
            l-=1
        elif(matrix[k-1][l-1][1]=="diag"):
            align1+=seqA[k-2]
            align2+=seqB[l-2]
            k-=1
            l-=1

align1=align1[::-1]
align2=align2[::-1]
print (align1)
print (align2)
Global(seqA,seqB)
```

Please can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Instead of posting it as a link to a Google doc, I recommend that you copy and paste the code for better readability.

Comment: Please include a minimal version of the code that illustrates the problem, inline in your question, not as a link to a external site.

Comment: I updated it to include the code. Sorry about that